# I want to make this select tag responsive while keeping it aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make this select tag responsive while keeping it aligned.I used form-control class but due to either my css or default css it is getting dis-aligned.and moreover the i want to make the background of search glyphicon coloured.

```
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="intro-text">

            <div class="intro-lead-in"><br>

            <div id="imaginary_container" align="center"> 
            <form action="search.php" method="get">
            <div class="input-group stylish-input-group col-md-9" >


                <input id ="search_bar" name= "search_bar" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" >



                <div class="input-group-addon">
               <select class="" name="select_course" >
                    <option value="course">Select </option>


                </select>
                </div>


                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <a href="search.php">
                    <button type="submit" action="search.php">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>  
                    </a>

                </span>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is responsive only. Based on select option length it will increase. If more content length in option it is also will be more. If you want to adjust it set width for all textbox,select,search icon in percentage.